# how to transpose data with multiple occurrences in sas

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I have a 2 column dataset - accounts and attributes, where there are 6 types of attributes.
I am trying to use PROC TRANSPOSE in order to set the 6 different attributes as 6 new columns and set 1 where the column has that attribute and 0 where it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer shows two approaches:

- `Proc TRANSPOSE`, and
- array based transposition using index lookup via hash.

For the case that all of the accounts missing the same attribute, there would be no way for the data itself to exhibit all the attributes -- ideally the allowed or expected attributes should be listed in a separate table as part of your data reshaping.

**Proc TRANSPOSE**

When working with a table of **only** `account` and `attribute` you will need to construct a view adding a numeric variable that can be transposed.  After `TRANSPOSE` the result data will have to be further massaged, replacing missing values (`.`) with `0`.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do account = 1 to 10;
    do attribute = 'a','b','c','d','e','f';
      if rand('uniform') < 0.75 then output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data stage / view=stage;
  set have;
  num = 1;
run;

proc transpose data=stage out=want;
  by account;
  id attribute;
  var num;
run;

data want;
  set want;
  array attrs _numeric_;
  do index = 1 to dim(attrs);
    if missing(attrs(index)) then attrs(index) = 0;
  end;
  drop index;
run;

proc sql;
  drop view stage;
```

From

[image]

To

[image]

**Advanced technique - Array and Hash mapping**

In some cases the `Proc TRANSPOSE` is deemed unusable by the coder or operator, perhaps very many by groups and very many attributes.  An alternate way to transpose attribute values into like named flag variables is to code:

- Two scans

  - Scan 1 determine attribute values that will be encountered and used as column names

    - Store list of values in a macro variable
  - Scan 2

    - Arrayify the attribute values as variable names
    - Map values to array index using hash (or custom informat per @Joe)
    - Process each group. Set arrayed variable corresponding to each encountered attribute value to `1`.  Array index obtained via lookup through hash map.

Example:

```
* pass #1, determine attribute values present in data, the values will become column names;
proc sql noprint; 
  select distinct attribute into :attrs separated by ' ' from have;

* or make list of attributes from table of attributes (if such a table exists outside of 'have');
*  select distinct attribute into :attrs separated by ' ' from attributes;

%put NOTE: &=attrs;

* pass #2, perform array based tranposformation;

data want2(drop=attribute);
  * prep pdv, promulgate by group variable attributes;
  if 0 then set have(keep=account);

  array attrs &attrs.;
  format &attrs. 4.;

  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash attrmap();
    attrmap.defineKey('attribute');
    attrmap.defineData('_n_');
    attrmap.defineDone();
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(attrs);
      attrmap.add(key:vname(attrs(_n_)), data: _n_);
    end;
  end;

  * preset all flags to zero;

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(attrs);
    attrs(_n_) = 0;
  end;

  * DOW loop over by group;

  do until (last.account);
    set have;
    by account;

    attrmap.find();     * lookup array index for attribute as column;
    attrs(_n_) = 1;     * set flag for attribute (as column);
  end;

  * implicit output one row per by group;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

One other option for doing this not using PROC TRANSPOSE is the data step array technique.

Here, I have a dataset that hopefully matches yours approximately.  ID is probably your account, Product is your attribute.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2007);
  do id = 1 to 4;
   do prodnum = 1 to 6;
    if rand('Uniform') > 0.5 then do;
      product = byte(96+prodnum);
      output; 
    end;
   end;
  end;
run;
```

Now, here we transpose it.  We make an array with the six variables that could occur in HAVE.  Then we iterate through the array to see if that variable is there. You can add a few additional lines to the `if first.id` block to set all of the variables to 0 instead of missing initially (I think missing is better, but YMMV).

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  array vars[6] a b c d e f;
  retain a b c d e f;
  if first.id then call missing(of vars[*]);
  do _i =  1 to dim(vars);
    if lowcase(vname(vars[_i])) = product then
          vars[_i] = 1;
  end;
  if last.id then output;
run;
```

We could do it a lot faster if we knew how the dataset was constructed, of course.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  array vars[6] a b c d e f;
  if first.id then call missing(of vars[*]);
  retain a b c d e f;
  vars[rank(product)-96]=1;
  if last.id then output; 
run;
```

While your data doesn't really work that way, you *could* make an informat though that did this.

```
*First we build an informat relating the product to its number in the array order;
proc format;
  invalue arrayi
  'a'=1
  'b'=2
  'c'=3
  'd'=4
  'e'=5
  'f'=6
  ;
  quit;
  
*Now we can use that!;
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  array vars[6] a b c d e f;
  if first.id then call missing(of vars[*]);
  retain a b c d e f;
  vars[input(product,arrayi.)]=1;
  if last.id then output; 
run;
```

This last one is probably the absolute fastest option - most likely much faster than PROC TRANSPOSE, which tends to be one of the slower procs in my book, but at the cost of having to know ahead of time what variables you're going to have in that array.